# Create with Webpack a Config File

Tags: webpack, config

I am trying to create a seperate config file.

I have tried to create a .js file but it didnt build it.

I want now to create a config file where i can edit the api url after i builded it. So i can edit the const everytime on the live environment

The first solution from Nico didn't solved my problem because i want it to create a complete new File which i can edit freely after i build my project. This only create it somewhere inside the dist folder where i cant find it.

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried it but it wont create me a file. I need to setup Webpack that this will create me a file inside the dist folder and there must be only one (Key/Value): apiurl = myURL.

But thanks for this help

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272128/how-to-load-an-external-config-file-in-a-webpack-react-application-without-bundl?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yeah this one helped me and it worked, but i'm not sure if this is the best solution ^^ but thank you & have a nice day